# Multigrid with different stencil

Tags: numerical-methods, poissons-equation, multigrid

I have a code for MultiGrid in 1D.

The code solves the Poisson equation with the central difference approximation.
$uL-2u+uR=f$.

I would like to generalize this approach and use it for the 
$uL-a u+uR=f$, (with $a \leftarrow 2-\epsilon$). The code works fine if $|\epsilon|>0.1$.

However it blows up if I choose $\epsilon =0.01$ it blows up. This happens with both cell center or cell vertex formulation. Is there anyway to fix this issue?
Thanks for your helps